# Help in calculating resistor values for AMS1117-adj

Tags: voltage-regulator

Wish to use AMS1117-adj to create Vin 5.0V, Vout 1.6-1.8V for 1-3 LEDs drawing 80ma each.

[image]

My calculations from the datasheets resulted in R1 and R2 values so low that they pulled more current than the load.

Used on-line calculator with the result about 3.3V, even after doubling and halving values of R1 and then R2.

Comment: How are the LEDs current limited?

Comment: Place a ~42 ohm from 5 V to each LED instead. Say 56//180 ohm.

Answer (score 3):

While it is possible to use an 1117 regulator as a constant current source, the images on your question show an incorrect diagram.

The ones on your question are for a *constant voltage supply*.

For constant current you need the following:

[image]

From [this](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/NCP1117LP-D.PDF) datasheet page 11.

To output 80mA:

0.08 = 1.25/R + Iadj

I'll ignore Iadj:

> Iadj, is
>   significantly lower and constant with respect to the
>   programmed load current, it generates a small output
>   voltage error that can usually be ignored.

0.08 = 1.25/R

R = 1.25/0.08 = ~15R

Comment: The reason I wanted a voltage regulator as vs constant current output is that the appliance might have anywhere between 1 and 4 LEDs. I wanted to build one circuit that would work with any of the appliances.

Comment: @ccyoung -- What is the voltage of your supply? Depending on how much you have available you could use from 1 up to 4 LEDs in series.

Comment: 5V power available

Comment: Then go with the resistors. Why did you want a regulator if you already have a regulated source..? Or did you want something else..? Now I'm confused.

Answer (score 1):

Why so complex? If you need 80 mA through an LED from a 5 volt supply, just use a dropper resistor. Voltage on LED = 1.7 volts so voltage across dropper resistor is 3.3 volts therefore, with 80 mA flowing, the resistor should be 41.3 ohms (with 41.2 ohms being a fairly standard resistor these days).

Using a linear voltage regulator won't save energy compared to using a resistor.