# Can I use an LDO voltage regulator as current limiter?

Tags: ldo

Like this, connect the ADJ and Vout of an LDO directly.

The principle of an LDO is to make Vout 1.25 V higher than ADJ. As they are connected, Vout can never be 1.25 V higher than ADJ, and the LDO internal resistance will be very low.

Meanwhile, the [AMS1117-ADJ](http://www.advanced-monolithic.com/pdf/ds1117.pdf) has an internal current limit, when a large current passes through the 1117, the 1117 shuts down.

A cheap simple current limit. Would it work?
[image]

Comment: From data sheet, thermal **shutdown** occurs @ +165C, but absolute maximum rating for the chip is only +125C: damage is possible. I infer from data sheet that internal current limit is meant for protection against *current transients*, and not so much for *steady-state*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a linear regulator as a constant current source, though it is generally not done the way your circuit shows.  It used to be very common to make a constant current source from a linear regulator.  Search for an LM317 constant current circuit and you will find plenty of examples.

Since you want to use a 1117 linear regulator, I searched a bit and found [this previous answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/270637/47070) that shows how the 1117 can be used.

From that answer:

[image]

That answer also links to a [good datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/ncp1117lp-d.pdf) which is also the source of the circuit diagram.

Keep the power rating for the resistor in mind.  \$P = I^2R\$, so for 1 ampere of current you'd need a resistor rated for over 1 watt.

---

LTspice says that your circuit will work.

I used this circuit:

[image]

It produced this output:

| Node | Value | Unit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| V(n001): | 10 | voltage |
| V(n002): | 0.0951755 | voltage |
| I(R1): | 0.951755 | device_current |
| I(V1): | -0.951755 | device_current |
| Ix(u1:1): | -5.5e-005 | subckt_current |
| Ix(u1:2): | -0.9517 | subckt_current |
| Ix(u1:3): | 0.951755 | subckt_current |

I(R1) is the current through your load.  For R1 greater than ~10 ohms, the current is proportional to R1.  For R1 less than 10 ohms, the current is limited to about 1 ampere.

You can't really tell at exactly what current level it will begin limiting.  The datasheet says "1.1 ampere," but the simulator limits to just under 1 ampere. You can use it, but the only way to find the real limit is to try it - and it will probably vary from device to device.

It doesn't matter whether you use a fixed voltage regulator or an adjustable regulator - both types will limit the current.

Comment: `It doesn't matter whether you use a fixed voltage regulator or an adjustable regulator` Any fixed regulator has voltage difference between gnd and out pins much greater than 1.25V Then the resistor will have to dissipate several times more watts. So using fixed voltage regulator for current limiting is impractical.

Comment: @Matt:  That refers to the circuit without a series resistor.  The one that relies on the internal current limiting of the 1117.

Answer (score 0):

According to TI's datasheet, the current limit is from 800 mA (max. continuous current, coincidentally) to 1.5 A. Additionally there's a temperature/power limit.

The usual way to use a voltage regulator to limit current used to be to use a *sense resistor* between the *out* and *adjust* terminals - obviously dissipating less with lower \$V_{adj}\text{ and }V_{IN} –
V_{OUT}\$.

Comment: That's an abusive amount of `use`s (and `to`s) in one sentence.

Answer (score -2):

Sadly no.

A voltage regulator outputs a set voltage on his out pin in respective to ground. On startup it would try, but would immediately be shut down by his own current protection because a high current is flowing from Vout to GND since there is (almost) no resistance.

You can use fuses to break the circuit, if you want to use them more than one time look into PPTC fuses.

Comment: `A voltage regulator outputs a set voltage on his Out-Pin in respective to Ground` Um, *no*. I think seafood's take on 3-ping voltage regulators correct. Why would load be `(almost) no resistance`?

Comment: Because seafood shorted output pin to ground.

Comment: @vindarmagnus: seafood shorted output pin to the *adj*ust pin, misleadingly labelled GND, too. But look where the GND symbol is in the schematic - and where it is not. (When you want a commenter notified of a comment of yours, mention their name as in @greybeard.)

Comment: The "ground" pin on a linear regulator would normally be connected to ground in the circuit, but it doesn't have a physical connection to circuit ground inside the IC.  Connecting Vout and Ground doesn't cause a short circuit.